# There anyway to apply a different filter to an action of a controller, than the parent controller has in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the beginning of my controller I have `filter_resource_access` which requires login for all actions on the controller.

However, for one action, I want to have a different authorization mechanism.

There anyway to have a different filter - perhaps a before_filter - for that action only without requiring the login that the parent filter requires ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filter_resource_access it looks like you have to change that out for custom before_filters and filter_access_to filters. [See here](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) search for 'filter_resource_access'.

You can specify which controller actions a filter applies to. You can either exclude or include actions like so:

```
before_filter :filter_action, :except => [:index, :edit]
before_filter :filter_action2, :only => [:index, :edit]
```

[Click here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) for the associated Rails docs. Check out the 'Filter chain skipping' and 'Filter conditions' sections.

Comment: Would I do this given that I am using declarative_authorization ? I guess what I am asking is if there is a decl_auth way of doing this, other than the Rails way of doing `before_filter` ?

Comment: I just updated my answer. It looks like if you want something custom you have to swap out filter_resource_access for some filter_access_to declarations.

Comment: Well...one more question, I did this: `filter_access_to :index, :new, :edit, :step, :create, :update, :destroy` on my controller. Which explicitly leaves out two actions. But when I execute those actions, it sends me to my login page. Why is that ? I thought it wouldn't filter it. I also don't have `filter_access_all` or any other filter on this particular controller - except for what it inherits from the ApplicationController.